# Prove there is a line that cuts the area in half

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, geometric-topology

Suppose you are given two compact, convex sets A and B in the plane, prove there exists a line such that the area of A and B is simultaneously divided in half.

Can you help me with this proof? What I think I have to do is give a fuction that measures the area and then use  intermediate value theorem, but I don't know how to give this function explicitly, I'm a third semester undergrad, so I cannot use very advanced tools.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @Will: That is incorrect. Consider a horizontal cut through the centroid of the letter T.

Comment: In $n$ dimensions, this is known as the [ham sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem). A proof for two dimensions, where it is called the two pancakes theorem, is given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTWP-4g_MQw).

Comment: @Will: A counterexample to your assertion: $([-100,100]\times[-\epsilon,\epsilon]) \cup ([-\epsilon,\epsilon]\times[-2,0])$ with $\epsilon\ll0.01$. The centroid is at approximately $(0,-0.01)$. Approximately 99% of the area is above the centroid.

Comment: @Will: If you want a counterexample with convex shapes, just consider a triangle.

Comment: some days it does not pay to get out of bed

Comment: Constructing the area functional is easy, just follow the video link in Rahul's comment. What is not so obvious is how to prove that function is continuous with respect to change of angle. You can use the fact that line always divide $A$ into two equal half to show the instantaneous center of rotation of the line (when you change the angle) falls inside $A$. This will allow you to bound the rate of change of the area of $B$ cut by the line...

Comment: This problem is addressed in "What is Mathematics", see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453448/for-any-convex-polygon-there-is-a-line-that-divides-both-its-area-and-perimeter/1453516#1453516). Anyway I would like to see a rigorous proof of continuity for the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a rough sketch of an idea, but I think it should work.

Put some kind of Cartesian coordinates down on the plane. For any $\theta \in [0, \pi]$,consider also a coordinate system obtained by rotation through this angle about the origin. Let $f_A$ and $f_B$ be functions defined by the property: the line defined by $x=f_A(\theta)$ in the corresponding coordinate system divides A into two parts of equal areas. Analogously for $B$.

Now set a function $g = f_A - f_B$ at every $\theta$. Since $g(\pi) = -g(0)$, the intermediate value theorem will show it is possible.

Comment: I think it is quite hard to show that this function is continuous. Maybe some of the convexity assumption can be made here to make the claim easier to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is convoluted so bear with me.

For any point x in the plane you can construct a line, L, from the origin of the plane through x.  For each real number r (positive or negative) you can construct a line perpendicular to L that is r distance from the origin.  Precisely one of these lines at a specific distance r from the origin will cut A is half.  (Basically, by the intermediate value theorem by considering a function that measures what portion of A is cut by the perpendicular line r distance from the origin.  The is contionous and goes from 0 to 100% and is monotonic so there is exactly one, r, where the result is 50%.)

Thus we can define f: Plane -> Real Numbers where f(x) is the real number r where the perpendicular line cuts A in half.  This is a continuous function.
Define g: Plane -> Real Numbers where g(x) is the real number r where the perpendicular line cuts B in half.
Define h(x) = f(x) - g(x).

By the fixed point theorem there must be a point y in the plane where h(y) is 0.  Then f(y) = g(x) = some real number r.  Find the line that is that is r distance from the origin and perpendicular to the line from y to the origin.
This line will cut both A and B in half.

Comment: It's basically the [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem[/link] the Ham Sandwich Theorem.

Comment: Arggh [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem

Comment: The [Ham sandwich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem)?

Comment: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem)

Comment: To be honest, I had never heard of it (at least not by that name) either until a few months ago.  It's one of the many surprising results of the fixed point theorem, which in  turn is basically a surprising result of the intermediate value theorem.  Sort of.

Comment: Note that this makes no use of convexity, and I think something needs to be said about continuity here. Also, some mathjax would be helpful

Comment: " (Basically, by the intermediate value theorem by considering a function that measures what portion of A is cut by the perpendicular line r distance from the origin. The is contionous and goes from 0 to 100% and is monotonic so there is exactly one, r, where the result is 50%.)"  This function is continuous *because* $A$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof via the Borsuk Ulam theorem for two dimensions. In fact it uses nothing about convexity, but lets keep compactness for now (this proof works for a broader class of subsets.)

**Lemma: ( 2d Borsuk Ulam)**  Every  continuous map $f:S^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, where $f(-\mathbf{x})=-f(\mathbf{x})$ has a zero.

$ax+by=c$ is a line granted that $a,b$ are not simultaneously zero.

The equation can be scaled so that the triple $(a,b,c) \in S^2$, by dividing by the appropriate factor.

Consider a "half space'' determined by a line. Given a point $(a,b,c) \in S^2$, we define
$$H^{+}(\mathbf{u}):=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid ax+by \leq c \}$$

In the most natural way, we extend this definition to include the ``lines at infinity:''
$$H^{+}((0,0,1))= \mathbb R^2 \, \, \,\,\,\,, H^{+}((0,0,-1))=\emptyset$$

Hence, Our "test space'' of all lines becomes the whole sphere $S^2$.

Consider the function $f:S^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $f(\mathbf{x})=(A_1(H^{+}(\mathbf{x}),A_2H^{+}(\mathbf{x}))$**, where $A_1,A_2$ are area functions for the two blobs.

The first thing to notice here, is that $$H^{+}(a,b,c)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid ax+by \leq c \},$$ while 
$$H^{+}(-a,-b,-c)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid ax+by \geq c \}.$$

Then, a solution to our problem is a root of $$g(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x})-f(-\mathbf{x})=0.$$

The Borsuk-Ulam theorem says this exists!

---

**proof of Lemma:** If $f:S^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is an odd function such that is nonvanishing, we can define $g(x):=f(x)/\|f(x)\|$, where $g:S^2 \to S^1$. However, since this is an odd map, it descends to $ \mathbb RP^2 \to  \mathbb RP^1 \cong S^1$, so $g_*:\pi_1(\mathbb R P^2) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ must be trivial, and hence there is a lift to $\mathbb R$, making the map $g_*$ nullhomotopic, contradicting the fact that $g(-x)=-g(x)$.

---

** We need to show that this assignment is continuous. Let's make these area functions formal by claiming them to be lebesgue measures on compact sets $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. It will suffice to show that for any $u_n \to u \in S^2$, we also have that $f(u_i) \to u$. Note that for some $x \in \mathbb R^2$ that is not on the boundary $\partial H^{+}(u)$ (which has measure zero since it is a line), we will have for sufficiently large $n$, $x \in H^{+}(u_n) \iff x \in H^{+}(u)$. This in turn means that the characteristic function $\chi_u$ on $H^{+}(U)$, we have that $\chi_{u_n} \to \chi(u)$ almost everywhere.

Hence by the compactness assumption, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem:

$$\mu_i(H^{+}u_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int \chi_{ u_n} d \mu_i\to \int \chi_u d \mu_i=\mu_i(H^+(u)),$$

as desired.